# Generate numbers using distribution in C or C++

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I am using gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11) compiler. [Uniform real distribution function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/uniform_real_distribution/) does not work in it. Is there some way I may generate numbers between 0 to 1 [0,1] in my present compiler according to

1. Uniform random distribution
2. Gaussian distribution
3. Exponential distribution.

I can not upgrade the compiler my project has a lot of dependencies on current 4.4.7 version.  Either C or C++ will work for me.

Comment: There is no standard function to do that before C++11 (only plain `rand`). Why you can't get modern compiler? If it is your home project it should be easy.

Comment: Perhaps it has `<tr1/random>`?

Comment: Are you looking for a [tag:C] solution, or a [tag:c++].  They solution could be different depending on the language

Comment: Have you looked at [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_random/reference.html)?

Comment: My condolences for being stuck with this very old compiler version..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have the libraries, I would grab a copy of  "Numerical Recipes in C" and write them yourself. Since they are copyrighted, I cannot copy them here. But chapter 7 has what you are looking for.

My copy is dated; however, still great for this stuff. 7.1 Uniform Deviates, 7.2 Normal Deviates, and 7.3 Poisson, Gamma, and Binomial Deviates.

--jon

Comment: Some older edition is available for free online. Maybe he will have to do some Fortran to C translation but this shouldnt be too hard